# PyroCMS will upload only on local XAMPP server not on hosting platform

Tags: codeigniter, upload, pyrocms

On my XAMPP server I have PyroCMS installed. Version 2.1.4 to be exact. When I go to upload files via the file browser in the admin page it will work. I installed the same version on my hosting platform and whenever I go to upload a PNG file it won't work. This is the error I get:

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

I checked the file size limits and changed them to no avail. I was then told I should check the mime type of the image and see if that type is in the CodeIgniter mime type declarations. I did that and it came back as: `image/png`. Which was in fact in the declaration in and array with `image/x-png`. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here? PNG is in the allowed file types and I am well out of ideas...

Comment: Have you see the logs? Maybe in the log file there are more informations.

Comment: Nope, nothing. The same vague "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Adding `text/plain` as a MIME type to the PNG array in CodeIgniter fixed it.

Comment: Where is this "Codeigniter" Mimes file in PyroCMS? Do you mean the PyroCMS Mimes in /system/cms/config/mimes.php and not /system/codeigniter/? I cant find a "codeigniter" mimes in /system/codeigniter/.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It was a system specific bug. Plus, this was on an outdated version of PyroCMS.

Comment: Ok, but this issue still exists in 2.1. and 2.2 for .ico files. I found out the Upload class in the Pyro CI checks images for only a few certain extensions, and fails the upload. .ico and svg are not in this list so they dont upload. Have reported this on Github https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/issues/2801